# I need to append items from one list to two others, but my database is squared when i run it through

Tags: python, list

```
train_imgs = []
train_lbs = []
test_imgs = []
test_lbs = []

i = 0
j = 0
print(len(array_resized))
for i in range(len(array_resized)):
  for j in range(24):
    train_imgs.append(array_resized[i])
    train_lbs.append(ar_label[i])
    j = j+1
  j = 0
  for j in range(6):
    test_imgs.append(array_resized[i])
    test_lbs.append(ar_label[i])
    j = j+1
  j = 0
```

I need to send 24 items to the train list, and then the next 6 to the test list, and then the next 24 to the train list and so on and so on, but the lenght of the final test and train lists sums up to 9000, instead of the initial 300. What can I do about it? Thank you in advance!

```
array_0 = [cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) for file in glob.glob("/content/imgs_3/0*")]
ar_label0 = ['0' for file in array_0]
array_1 = [cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) for file in glob.glob("/content/imgs_3/1*")]
ar_label1 = ['1' for file in array_1]

and so on.. until array9

array_all = array_0+array_1+array_2+array_3+array_4+array_5+array_6+array_7+array_8+array_9

array_resized = [cv2.resize(file, (28,28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR) for file in array_all]
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thank you for the notice! It's my first post, I've corrected it :)

Comment: How does your `array_resized` list look like?

Comment: i'll edit it into the post, arrays_0 through 9 contain 30 images each of handwritten digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about parsing up your list:

```
for i in range(0, len(array_resized), 30):
  for j in range(24):
    train_images.append(array_resized[i+j])
    train_images.append(array_resized[i+j])
  for j in range(6):
    test_images.append(array_resized[i+24+j])
    test_images.append(array_resized[i+24+j])
```

In your code you essentially added 24 instances of each term of the original list to the train list, and 6 to the test list. This is because you loop through the entire length of the original list. In my code I looped through chunks of 30, each consisting of 24 train elements and 6 test elements.

Note: In python, for loops are much more intuitive than other languages. Python abides by the ideas of [*Functional Programming*][1], which generally makes life a lot easier.

W3Schools has a pretty good lesson on for loops, and all their little quirks.

link: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

[1]: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0#:~:text=Functional%20programming%20(often%20abbreviated%20FP,state%20flows%20through%20pure%20functions.

Comment: Tysm! this did the trick. Coming from c++, I've been having trouble with python's for loops so I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Yeah Python is cool, all sorts of niche functions that make life a lot easier:)

Little selfish note: If you could upvote my answer, and mark it as correct, I'd greatly appreciate that:)

Comment: Can't upvote yet, but it's been marked!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating the entire process.

From what I see you want to split your data into a training and test set (although you should split it into a training, validation and test set). You want 80% training images and 20% test images.

I would take `array_resized`, shuffle it (so you have a random split) and then choose the first 80% for training and the remaining 20% for testing:

```
import random

# shuffle list
random.shuffle(array_resized)

# get the split
length = len(array_resized)
train_split = int(length * 0.8)  # 80% percent of the data

train_imgs = array_resized[:train_split]  # choose the first 80% of the images
test_imgs = array_resized[train_split:]  # choose the remaining images
```

Comment: Yess, that would be the easiest way but my labels have to match my images perfectly, so that annoying little bit makes everything more complicated :s!

Comment: right, although you could combine the two lists with `zip()`, shuffle the combined variable and then split it up again as explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-shuffle-two-lists-with-same-order/)

Comment: Or, instead of creating separate arrays for images and labels, you could create arrays that contain both, like so: `array_0 = [[cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), '0'] for file in glob.glob("/content/imgs_3/0*")]` - so you'll have a lists of lists, where each sub-list contains an image and a label.